# Set equal distance between UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

How to set equal distance between four UIButton ?

Setting this constraints the result in iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus is wrong.
With this constraints:
[image]
 [image]
Result:
[image]

Comment: use UIStackView horizontal view stack . check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: Or you could place three transparent views between green buttons and make this views equal to each other. As well as pin view's heads and tails between each pair of green buttons.

Comment: Why are you aligning center x ? you should not do that instead define a constraint between first button and second button horizontally. And make sure the horizontal constraint between all the buttons are of equal length, i mean the constant value

Comment: Embed all the button in uiview and the set constraints to each button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply constraints as below screen shots to achieve required result.

**There is not need of extra view.**

**Pure Autolayout.**

1) Below are the constraints for button1.
[image]

2) Below are the constraints for button2.
[image]

3) Below are the constraints for button3.

[image]

4) Below are the constraints for button4.

[image]

**Below is the result for iPhone6+ simulator.**
Portrait : [image]

Landscap : [image]

Portrait With different background color from more clear view:
[image]

Lanscape With different background color from more clear view:
[image]

Comment: Ok it works really fine! Can you explain detailed how?

Comment: any view required x,y,width,height using constraint to setup properly,

Comment: First for button B1, we have added left and bottom and height, so from left const. it will get x value, from (bottom,height) const. B1 will get height and y value, only there is one value missing i.e. width of B1, we will add this leter on

Comment: then for button b2, we have added left, bottom and height, so it will also get y and height value, it will not get x value, because width of button B1 is not calculate yet or you can say button b1 have not enough const. to calculate its width, and left of b2 is depends on b1

Comment: similarly we will add for the button b3, so b3 will also have  y and height value, as like b2, b3 will also not get x value because width of b2 is also not fixed

Comment: For button b4, we will add left, right bottom and height cont. so it will get height and y value, like button b2 and b3 it will also not get x value.

Comment: next step is to give equal relative width to all button, so will drag from button  b1 to b2, and will give equal width, when we will do the same for all, then runtime it will deside the width of any button, using totalViewWidth(say 320)-space(here we have total 5 gaps in between, including left and right, say 5*20 = 100), so 320-100 = 220, the it will divide 220/4 runtime and give equal width to all buttons

Comment: I am happy to know that, you understood very well, you are most welcome.

Comment: I've understood but I wanted to be sure of that. Thank you